# How to convert an ECDSA key from hex to PEM format

Tags: openssl, format, public-key, ecdsa

I have a hex string that allegedly contains an EC public key. I need to convert this hex string to PEM format ("key.pem" in following example) in order to investigate the contents which I plan to do with "openssl ec -in key.pem -text -noout". Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you're starting with a hex string, you need to hex decode it to get the DER-encoding first.

The hex string should start with `30...` which is indicates that it's an ASN.1 sequence.

This shell command will hex decode (using `xxd`), then use OpenSSL to parse the resulting DER public key:

```
echo "30...." | xxd -r -p - | openssl ec -inform der -pubin -noout -text
```

To output a PEM, remove `-noout -text`, add `-pubout -out publickey.pem`

```
echo "30...." | xxd -r -p - | openssl ec -inform der -pubin -pubout -out publickey.pem
```

If it's actually a private key, just omit `-pubin` and `-pubout`.

Comment: I ran into the same issue as the question author, in my case the hex source is ECDSA openssl module, and no, hex provided by EC_POINT_point2hex is not ASN.1 sequence, not starting with 30 and usually too long; the only way to decode this hex so far is using reverse EC_POINT_hex2point directly in C, I failed to achieve anything useful within bash. This hex has nothing to do with base64-decoded contents of PEM, by the way, and it also has no information upon curve used (you have to make sure it is proper yourself, otherwise key will be useless).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by hex, you mean a binary (DER formatted) key?  Or is this hex string in a human readable file with a header beginning with "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----"?  If you see that header, it is already in PEM format.

If it's in binary format, try this to convert a binary key to pem:

```
openssl ec -in key.der -inform DER -pubin -out keyout.pem -outform PEM
```

where "key.der" is your binary key.

But, you should also be able to investigate the contents without converting to PEM.  Just use:

```
openssl ec -in key.der -inform DER -pubin -text -noout
```

Comment: I know nothing about the key with the exception of the following: 
- 114 characters long (each character in the range 0-9 and A through F, thus 57 bytes); 
-allegedly it contains a public ECDSA key

Comment: First command returns (the hex string in "key"):
# openssl ec -in key -inform DER -pubin -out keyout.pem -outform PEM
read EC key
unable to load Key
3073398984:error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long:asn1_lib.c:142:
3073398984:error:0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:bad object header:tasn_dec.c:1306:
3073398984:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:381:Type=X509_ALGOR
3073398984:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:751:Field=algor, Type=X509_PUBKEY

Comment: Second:
# openssl ec -in key -inform DER -pubin -text -noout
read EC key
unable to load Key
3073931464:error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long:asn1_lib.c:142:
3073931464:error:0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:bad object header:tasn_dec.c:1306:
3073931464:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:381:Type=X509_ALGOR
3073931464:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:751:Field=algor, Type=X509_PUBKEY

Comment: Since it's a public key, do you mind posting it here, so we can look at it and try to figure out what format it is in?